# XML Schema Validation in Android - getting "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Tags: java, android, xsd, xerces, xml-validation

I've searched and I've searched, but I have no idea what's wrong. I know standard Android libraries don't have support for Schema or xml validation, and you can't use Apache Xerces out of the box, so I'm using this library:
https://code.google.com/p/xerces-for-android/

People seem to have success with this library, but I do not. This is my code:

```
private boolean validateDocument() {

    boolean result;

    try {

        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xml_schema);
        File file = context.getFileStreamPath(fileName);

        Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(is);
        Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(file);

        SchemaFactory factory = new XMLSchemaFactory();
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);

        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

        validator.validate(xmlFile);

        result = true;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        result = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        result = false;
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}
```

I am not confident that my xml_schema file is correct, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. In any case, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="manifest" type="ManifestType" />

    <xs:complexType name="ManifestType" >
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="base_url" type="BaseUrl" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="current_version" type="CurrentVersion" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="version" type="VersionType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="BaseUrl" >
        <xs:attribute name="url" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="CurrentVersion" >
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="zip_url" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="build_md5" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType >

    <xs:complexType name="VersionType" >
        <xs:sequence >
            <xs:element name="file" type="FileType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="add" type="AddType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="remove" type="RemoveType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="build_md5" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="prefix" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="FileType" >
        <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="url" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="md5" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="patch" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="file" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="permissions" use="required" >
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer" >
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="777" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="AddType" >
        <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="url" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="file" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="permissions" use="required" >
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer" >
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="777" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="RemoveType" >
        <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I don't have an exact XML file that this is supposed to validate, but here is the sample that I am using for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >

    <base_url url="https://whatever.com" />
    <current_version id="someversion"
                     zip_url="somedownloadurl.zip"
                     build_md5="true" />

    <version id="versionA" build_md5="md5sum" prefix="rom_update_version=" >
        <file path="path/of/example" url="https://someurl.com" md5="md5sum" patch="path/of/example/file.patch" file="path/of/example/file" name="file" permissions="645" />
        <file path="path/of/example2" md5="md5sum" patch="path/of/example2/file2.patch" file="path/of/example2/file2" name="file2" permissions="665" />

        <add path="path/of/example3" file="path/of/example3/file3" name="file3" permissions="333" />

        <remove path="path/of/example4" name="file4" />
    </version>

    <version id="versionB" build_md5="md5sum" prefix="rom_update_version=" >
        <file path="path/of/example" md5="md5sum" patch="path/of/example/file.patch" file="path/of/example/file" name="file" permissions="777" />
        <file path="path/of/example2" url="https://someurl.com" md5="md5sum" patch="path/of/example2/file2.patch" file="path/of/example2/file2" name="file2" permissions="775" />

        <add path="path/of/example3" file="path/of/example3/file3" name="file3" permissions="333" />

        <remove path="path/of/example4" name="file4" />
    </version>
</manifest>
```

Here is the full exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:73)
    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:55)
    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.reset(XMLSchemaLoader.java:999)
    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:536)
    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:515)
    at mf.org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:237)
    at mf.javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:611)
    at wav.demon.cognitionupdate.XMLRetriever.XMLParser.validateDocument(XMLParser.java:116)
    at wav.demon.cognitionupdate.XMLRetriever.XMLParser.<init>(XMLParser.java:78)
    at wav.demon.cognitionupdate.XMLRetriever.TestUpdate.doInBackground(TestUpdate.java:70)
    at wav.demon.cognitionupdate.XMLRetriever.TestUpdate.doInBackground(TestUpdate.java:28)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    ... 4 more
```

`at wav.demon.cognitionupdate.XMLRetriever.XMLParser.validateDocument(XMLParser.java:116)` is the first of my code, and it is the `Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);` line.

I've searched and searched and searched for the solution to this problem, but I am just clueless. Everywhere I look it looks like I'm doing it right, but this just isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're xml file is not valid

Comment: The schema file or the test xml file?

Comment: both, check my answer. But you should have flagged straight away that the xml is invalid: <manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi="noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="xml_schema.xsd" >

Comment: I see, I added that line a few minutes ago in my search of finding a solution; I didn't see the typo.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both your xml data/xml scheme and they are both invalid:

http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/ and even the java stack is saying that.

Comment: I had no idea this site existed, I will look into it.

Comment: Okay, I edited the original post to show my changes, the xml files are now valid, according to the site you linked to. I am getting the exact same error message, though.

Comment: I've no idea then, just one last thing I would check: Are you sure you're referencing all the jars, adding them to the build path?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm using Android Studio and everything is added in and compiles fine.

Comment: Are you sure; Android studio is not even a beta release, so maybe something is missing. What I am saying that that the xerces library that you're calling directly maybe in the in path, but other it depends upon might not, hence the errors during run-time.

Comment: That's probably the issue, thought it would be an Android runtime issue and not an IDE issue. This library is supposed to have all the dependencies to correctly run on Android, but I don't think that is the case, as I am having other problems with it elsewhere. They claim that it works properly on Android 4.2, which is what I am on, so I am clueless as to what is wrong.

Comment: I might be wrong on this, but I think that Android is java 6 se compliant(harmony), so can't you just use harmony standard libraries? Also given that that IDE is in early stage of development, maybe swap to eclise.